# design using a readonly class in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Small design question here. I'm trying to develop a calculation app in C#. I have a class, let's call it InputRecord, which holds 100s of fields (multi dimensional arrays) This InputRecordclass will be used in a number of CalculationEngines. Each CalculcationEngine can make changes to a number of fields in the InputRecord. These changes are steps needed for it's calculation.

Now I don't want the local changes made to the InputRecord to be used in other CalculcationEngine's classes.

The first solution that comes to mind is using a struct: these are value types. However I'd like to use inheritance: each CalculationEngine needs a few fields only relevant to that engine: it's has it's own InputRecord, based on BaseInputRecord.

Can anyone point me to a design that will help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have a lot of data, using structs or common cloning techniques may not be very space-efficient (e.g. it would use much memory).

Sounds like a design where you need to have a "master store" and a "diff store", just analogous to a RDBMS you have data files and transactions.

Basically, you need to keep a list of the changes performed per calculation engine, and use the master values for items which aren't affected by any changes.

Comment: Interesting. I'll think about this

Answer (score 2):

The elegant solution would be to *not* change the inputrecord. That would allow sharing (and parallel processing).

If that is not an option you will have to Clone the data. Give each derived class a constructor that takes the base Input as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a Clone() method on your BaseInputRecord, then pass a copy to each CalculationEngine.

Comment: Clone seems like a good idea, you will have the original records  intact and other calculation engines will have seperate copies.

Comment: I have considered cloning but the amount of fields keep me from using this strategy